# Initialisation of string elementwise causes TLE but this technique works fine

Tags: c++, string, initialization

I was just solving a problem on strings. I had to initialise whole the string by 'a'. The size of string
n could be as large as 10^5 .I used the brute force approach to initialise each element by loops.

```
 string s;  
 for(int i = 0;i < n;i++)s[i]='a';
```

When I went to print the string by using

```
cout<<s;
```

Nothing was printed! To print the string I had to print it elementwise:-

```
 for(int i=0;i<n;i++)cout<<s[i];
```

Also, This method gave TLE.

But, When I initialised the string like this

```
string s(n,'a');
```

the solution was accepted. And I was able to print whole string altogether.
Why is such huge difference just caused by just different initialisation techniques?

Comment: `string s;` declares an empty string. Indexing past the end of it is incorrect. You either need to resize it to the right length or use `push_back` or `+=` to add to it.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Is this declaration correct  `string s[n];`

Comment: `string s[n]` is an array of `n` `string`s, not a `string` of size `n`.

Comment: @user4581301 So, How should I declare a string of size n? To avoid such undefined behaviour

Comment: Pretty much `string s(n,'a');`. You have to put some character in. Or you can `string s; s.resize(n)` and then loop, but no advantage to it over  `string s(n,'a');`. Probably not appreciably slower, but more code means more places to screw up.

Answer (score 1):

```
string s;
```

declares a string of size 0. Indexing into this string with `[]` will invoke undefined behavior. One result could be a TLE.

You can initialize the string with size `n`, and initialize all the elements to the same char:

```
string s(n,'a');
```

If you want to use a loop, you can do:

```
string s;
for(int i = 0;i < n;i++) s += 'a';
```

Comment: How Should the string of size n be declared then?

Comment: The way you did it originally, in the question.

Comment: But what could one do to declare a string without initialising it?

Comment: But, The way I did originally was invoking undefined behaviour as you said.

Comment: I've edited the answer. Let me know which part is unclear.

Comment: The behaviour in strictest sense is not undefined we not always get TLE it is just for large $n$. We can also as usual do all regular operations on individual characters of the string, but the string as whole is just empty.

Comment: No, it's undefined. That means the code may work sometimes as well.

Comment: I am used to such declaration and this never did any problem to me. Usually when I declare such strings and read the strings entirely from the input, I am able to do print the entire string in one go.

Comment: Again, indexing at an invalid position is UB. The code might still work, there's just no guarantee that it will.

Comment: But how would we declare a string whose size is not given, we are given the string in input and we have to find it's size.

Comment: Depends entirely on how the input is given. We can play tag on this all week, [or we can point you at some good documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) so you can read about all the groovy things  you can do with a `string`.